# MongoDb replica-server getting killed due to less memory?

Tags: mongodb, replication

Require a huge help here, since this is affecting our production instance.

One of the replica server is failing due to lack of memory (see below chunk of piece from kern.log)

```
kernel: [80110.848341] Out of memory: kill process 4643 (mongod) score 214181 or a child
kernel: [80110.848349] Killed process 4643 (mongod)
```

**UPDATE**

```
kernel: mongod invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_adj=0
kernel: [85544.157191] mongod cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
kernel: [85544.157195] Pid: 7545, comm: mongod Not tainted 2.6.32-318-ec2
```

**Insight:**

1. Primary server DB size is 50GB out of which 30GB is filled by index.
2. Primary server has 7GB Ram whereas secondary server has 3.1GB Ram.
3. Both servers are 64-bit machine and running Debian/Ubuntu respectively.
4. Running Mongo 2.0.2 on both servers

Note:
I see a similar [issue has been created](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5312) in Jira-Mongo web-site recently - no answer to that yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you got swap enabled on these instances?  While generally not needed for mongoDB operation it can prevent the process from being killed by the kernel when you hit an OOM situation.  That is mentioned here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Production+Notes#ProductionNotes-Swap

The issue referenced is happening during a full re-sync rather than ongoing production replication - is that what you are doing also?

Once you get things stable, take a look at your Res memory in mongostat or MMS, if that is exceeding or close to 3GB you should consider upgrading your secondary.

Comment: Yes this issue is happening during re-sync - I have installed this server and added as a replica-member and I believe Mongo will do re-sync in secondary server (?)

Comment: Has the secondary got a swap partition?  In all likelihood it is being killed because the sync and subsequent index build are consuming too much of its RAM - adding swap should stop that, but will mean it's going to run slowly

Comment: as per your suggestion I have added a swap file which wasn't there, let me see if that helps out.

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: @DeepKapadia I was running Mongo 2.0.2 on both the servers.

Comment: @AdamC adding/enabling SWAP really helped this situation I did not see mongo process killed for more than 10 hours now and it's keeping up really well, not sure if this is a permanent solution but it worked for me for now. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. One of the things to check is how many open connections you have. run the lsof command to see the open files associated with the mongod process. Try disabling journaling and see if you see a smaller number of open files. If so, let the replica catch up and then re-enable journaling. That might help. Adding swap should help too or if possible temporarily up the RAM.

Comment: I am afraid to remove journaling and re-enable them, adding a swap memory helped me.